# use node variable to get what the mouse is hovering on

Tags: javascript, jquery

For a project I was working on, I was instructed to use a node variable to find out what element and what part of the element the mouse is hovering.

What is a node variable and how do i use it to achieve the above?

An instance or example of what i am trying to do, if it helps, is find out what element or if possible what part of an element the mouse is over. Meaning, if the mouse is hovering over a `<p>` in the html document, i want to know that and if possible exactly what text inside said `<p>` in the mouse is over. Well, i don't need to know the words, i just want the words to be stored in a variable so i can apply CSS styles to them.

I really appreciate any and all help with this.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) that returns the target of the event:

> The DOM element that initiated the event.

```
$('body').on("mouseover", function(e){
   $(e.target).addClass('hovered');
   alert($(e.target).text())
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ffkQF/1/)

Comment: thank you for the demo, it helped me understand what I need to do

Answer (score 0):

a node variable is a variable that stores a DOM node, to use it you create a mouse tracking event handlers and process the parameters that are sent to you by the browser when these events occur. one of these parameters is the element (node) that triggered the event.

this link can help you to get started: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/MouseEvent

Answer (score 0):

You can select nodes using `document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll` in newer browsers. Using CSS-style selectors, these methods will return nodes matching your selectors which you can then store in variables using something like

`var node = document.querySelectorAll(".someClassName"); //finds all nodes having class "someClassName"`

In order to detect mouse events on the node, you need to use the `addEventListener`[(MDN docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) or `attachEvent` methods, and listen for a `mouseover` event. If your project allows it, use jQuery to make your life easier.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it made things easier to understand. I am using jQuery :-)